# Web2py DAL has no attribute?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-ec2, web2py

My web2py application returned me an error today, which is quite odd.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 212, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/var/www/web2py/applications/1MedCloud/controllers/default.py", line 475, in <module>
  File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 194, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/var/www/web2py/applications/1MedCloud/controllers/default.py", line 63, in patient_register
    rows = db(db.patientaccount.email==email).select()
  File "/var/www/web2py/gluon/dal.py", line 7837, in __getattr__
    return ogetattr(self, key)
AttributeError: 'DAL' object has no attribute 'patientaccount'
```

I am using Mysql as the database, and the table 'patientaccount' does exist. There is no connection issue as I can create tables but not fetch them from the server.

I have been using the very same code to do the db thing, here is my code

```
db = DAL('mysql://###:$$$@^^^^^^:3306/account_info', pool_size=0)
    rows = db(db.patientaccount.email==email).select()
```

I did not change any code in my default.py file, but accidentally deleted some files inside "database" folder in my application. But I doubt if that could result the error, since the module is fetching tables on the server rather than using local files.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DAL does not inspect the MySQL database to discover its tables and fields. You must define the data models explicitly. So, somewhere in your code, you must do:

```
db.define_table('patientaccount',
    Field('email'),
    ...)
```

That will define the `db.patientaccount` table so the DAL knows it exists and what fields it includes.

Comment: Thank you! That exactly solve the issue! Honestly, I did not see anything regarding this in the document. Also wondering if future builds would include auto fetching functions.

Comment: I suppose the book could be a little more explicit about this, but throughout the book, every example involving the DAL includes table definitions, even when working with legacy databases. Note, there are scripts for inspecting [MySQL](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/extract_mysql_models.py), [PostgreSQL](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/extract_pgsql_models.py), and [SQLite](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/extract_sqlite_models.py) databases and auto-generating DAL models.

Comment: The book has no real life examples. There is no example how to use pyDAL with exsisting tables. That's a pity.

Comment: @Marek Marczak, not sure what you mean. The section on [legacy databases](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Legacy-databases-and-keyed-tables) shows an example table definition for a legacy table. And if the existing table has an auto-incrementing ID field, there is no difference in working with new vs. pre-existing tables. What exactly are you looking for?